# How to loop through dict of lists and pass variables into Ansible role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have an Ansible role that uses the variables: connection_name, connection_ip, etc. in order to create a connection.

In my hosts files, I could have numerous "connections" and have defined it as a dictionary of lists:

```
host_file:
hosts:
    host_one:
        domain: one
        ip: 172.18.1.1
        connection:
                - connection_name: two
                  connection_ip: 172.18.1.2

                - connection_index: three
                  local_hub_ip: 172.18.1.3

    host_two:
        domain: two
        ip: 172.18.1.2

    host_three:
        domain: three
        ip: 172.18.1.3
```

How do I pass in each "connection" object into my Ansible role so that it can use the nested variables "connection_name" and "connection_ip"? I have attempted using "with_items" and "with_dict" like so:

```
---
- name: Creating new connection
  hosts: "{{ host_name }}"
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  remote_user: "{{ user | default('root')}}"
  tasks:
      - include_role:
            name: connection-create
         with_items: "{{connection}}"
```

But I get a "FAILED: connection_name is undefined" because it passes in the object as {"connection_name": two, "connection_ip": 172.18.1.2}, instead of the inner portion, "connection_name": two, "connection_ip": 172.18.1.2 without the {}.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `connection` is a list of dictionnaries,

so use `item.connection_name` and `item.connection_ip` in your task.

Take a look at the official doc on [playbook loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops)